# XmlDocument, and special ISO Latin characters

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encoding

I'm trying to load up xml into an XmlDocument, but it doesn't recognize the encoded '&eacute' and throws an error 'An error occurred while parsing Entity Name'.  Now I can add a custom entity set in a DTD of my xml, so the XmlDocument loads properly.  But what I'm hoping is that I can reference a url that has a common set of these ISO Latin encoded characters.  Is this possible, or do I need to inject a custom list of DTD sets?

Comment: &eacute is used in HTML, not XML.  You need a properly encoded xml document.

Comment: You can have html encoded characters in an xml document: '&lt;' for example.  This is valid as far as .Net is concerned.  In order to properly encode the document xml needs to know about not standard html encodings, which as far as I can tell, is some subset of Ascii.  I can specify a DTD tag, that will map '&eacute' to 'É', but I would like a way to include a more comprehensive tag list from a defined DTD.  This article has a good description: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/827070-xml-character-codes-such

Answer (score 0):

[ISO/IEC 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)?

**EDIT**: To be more complete: there are no default URI to entiry ISO 8859 charset, so you'll need to create a custom DTD file to load that character entities.

Comment: Right, I'm looking to see if there is a dtd out there that has characters defined in this ISO format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it requires the closing ; ?

`&eacute;`